# xml parser configuration file

Tags: java, xml, file, properties, xml-parsing

I'm writing a simple XML parser in java,

Please explain how I can read XML tag names from a properties file?
example: if there is XML file like

```
<parent>
    <child>1</child>
    <child2>2</child2>
</parent>
```

I want to read tag names from configuration file. Here is the code I'm currently working on and I'm using an test.xml file to read data from.

```
public class xml2 
{
    public void xmlR(File f)
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream IF=new FileInputStream(f);
            DataInputStream data=new DataInputStream(IF);
            BufferedReader buf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(data));
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("test");

            File file=new File("xml.txt");
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) 
                {

                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) 
                {

                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    writer.write("ID : " + getTag("id", eElement));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("Name : " + getTag("Name", eElement));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.write("AGE: " + getTag("age", eElement));
                    writer.newLine();
                    writer.flush();
                    writer.write("-----------------------");writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String getTag(String sTag, Element eElement) 
    {
        NodeList nlList = eElement.getElementsByTagName(sTag).item(0).getChildNodes();

        Node nValue = (Node) nlList.item(0);

        return nValue.getNodeValue();
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        xml2 x=new xml2();
        x.xmlR(new File("test.xml"));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/). I think it's a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown your configuration file, so it's not possible to give you working code, but usually for this kind of XML the simplest approach is to get each value from the configuration file using an XPath expression of the form `/config/param[@name=$xxx]/@value`.

You're using DOM, which seems to be the default choice of Java programmers new to XML. But DOM is old, bloated, and unfriendly: the only reason people use it is that it's built in to the JDK. There are much better alternatives, such as JDOM and XOM.